# If menu item has submenu items, toggle the submenu on click

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to use jQuery to toggle the display of a drop-down sub-menu.

What I want to say in jQuery-speak is something like this:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
   if 'ul li' has a child 'ul' {
      if that child 'ul' is not visible {
         show it;
         } else if {
      the child 'ul' is visible {
         hide it;
         }
   } else if ('ul li') doesn't have a child 'ul' {
   do nothing;
}
```

I'd appreciate it if someone knowledgeable in jQuery could help me by translating my mambo-jumbo into actual jQuery code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
   var li = $(this).closest('li');
   if(li.has('ul'))
        li.find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Try this, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vsqa9/1/)